# Display Data to textfield from selected dropdown CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I tried to display data from the selected option to TextField.
I even tried some tutorial on internet but none of them work.

**Database :**

```
 id     user_name      email

 001    john           john@gmail.com
 002    karen          karen@gmail.com
```

If i click on **john** *user_name*,i want the email textfield filled with **john@gmail.com**

---

**View :**

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
   <label>Account</label>
      <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="account" name="account">
          <option value="">---Select Account---</option>
             <?php foreach ($account as $d) : ?>
                 <option value="<?= $d->id ?>"><?= $d->user_name ?></option>
             <?php endforeach; ?>
      </select>
      <small class="text-danger"><?= form_error('account') ?></small>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label>Email</label>
       <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?= set_value('email') ?>">
       <small class="text-danger"><?= form_error('email') ?></small>
 </div>
```

I try with this script but it didn't work

**Jquery:**

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#account').change(function(){
      $('#email').val($(this).find('option:selected').data('email'));
  });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code, you are not setting `data-email` for the `option` tag. change your php code to

```
 <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="account" name="account">
          <option value="">---Select Account---</option>
             <?php foreach ($account as $d) : ?>
                 <option value="<?= $d->id ?>" data-email="<?= $d->email?>"><?= $d->user_name ?></option>
             <?php endforeach; ?>
      </select>
```